# PgAdmin 4 Unexpectedly Quits on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, postgresql-14

I'm using the **M2 Mac Pro** 14 and I've reinstalled **PostgreSQL through Brew** and pgAdmin4 through the web-site, separately. However, I'm facing an issue where I can't open PgAdmin 4; it keeps showing an "**pgAdmin has unexpectedly finished**" error. Previously, it was working fine until I uninstalled it. I'm unsure about the reasons behind this problem.

**Here is a part of error report**

Process:               pgAdmin 4 [2293]
Path:                  /Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/MacOS/pgAdmin 4
Identifier:            org.pgadmin.pgadmin4
Version:               7.5 (4280.88)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Translated)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]

Date/Time:             2023-08-23
OS Version:            macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 5500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       370 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000020

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation  fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [2293]

VM Region Info: 0x20 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140723125682144

REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
UNUSED SPACE AT START

**Here are the steps I've taken so far:**

1. Uninstalled using Brew.
2. Deleted the "pgAdmin" and "PostgreSQL 14" folder from the "/Library" directory.
3. Removed "PostgreSQL 14" and "PostgreSQL Server" from "Directory Utility."
   (I did this 'cause when I try adding a new user account on my Mac, every time I add "postgres", Mac OS says I already have that, which I haven't)
4. Reinstalled PostgreSQL using the .dmg file from the official website.
5. However, during step #4, I encountered a password issue, so I uninstalled it again using the PostgreSQL uninstaller in the terminal.
6. Tried reinstalling using "brew install postgresql@14." and "pgAdmin" from the web site.
7. Unfortunately, the "The program has unexpectedly finished" error keeps persisting.

**I'm seeking guidance on what else I can do to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)**

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a similar problem. To resolve it, I uninstalled pgAdmin and then installed the most recent version, pgAdmin 7.6. This action resolved the issue for me. https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v7.6/macos/

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot:) and sorry I checked so late